# Getting a wrong length when printing an array in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, firefox, console.log

When doing a `console.log` of an array, I get the following results:

[image: 25 != 27] [image: 27 == 27]

What does the number (25) represent in the first picture (at the top)? My array has a length of 27, not 25. I thought it was the count of non-`null` values, but the second picture tells otherwise.

The (25) and (27) are also present in the reduced form:

[image: 25 != 27] [image: 27 == 27]

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

The code that leads to this behaviour:

```js
var lows = ts2values[current_ts];
var highs = ts2values[current_ts];

console.log("lows b : ", lows);
console.log("highs b : ", highs);

lows.push(null);
highs.push(null);

console.log("lows a : ", lows);
console.log("highs a : ", highs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the number (25) represent in the first picture (at the top)?

The length of the array **at that time**.

You can see the same result by the following code.

```js
myArray = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(myArray)

myArray.push(4, 5, 6)
console.log(myArray)
```

the first log is `Array(3)`

[image: console, not expand the array]

and expanding the first log, the length of the array is 6, not 3 because it was updated after `console.log`

[image: console, expand the array]